# EFCachingProvider for EF 4.0 by J. Kowalski is not Invalidating cached data

Tags: entity-framework-4, second-level-cache

I have a problem with [EFCachingProvider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32). It caches what I want but when SaveChanges is called on the context for a specific table it is not invalidating references to this table. It is a lot of code to post.
I'll be greteful if someone can explain how the invalidation is done, what are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I was using TransactionScope. After I removed it the issue was resolved. I'm no sure how to get it working alongside though.